# Laravel/SQL: How to fetch data from multiple table in a single query? that too using 'where'

Tags: sql, laravel

Working on a search functionality on Laravel App(Blog/Posts).
There are multiple types of posts (each having a separate table in the database)
Like Business posts, Social Life posts etc..

Below is the search function on SearchController

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function search(Request $request, $query = null)
{
    if($query == null)
        return redirect()->route('home');

    $search = Business::where([['title','like','%'.$query.'%'],['status','=',1]])
                        ->orWhere([['description','like','%'.$query.'%'],['status','=',1]])                         
                        ->paginate(10);

    return view('front.search',[
        'results' => $search,
        'query' => $query
    ]);
}
```

}

So basically my question is how to add other types of Post's table also?

My main motive is that when someone searches for anything, the result should be fetched from all types of posts table(business, nature, life & so on..).

Comment: `with()` and then choosing a relationship

Comment: Cannot use with(), as all the post types are in different tables and are not related (relationship not defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to maintain common id in both the table**

**NOTE: Join is the preferable method**

```
   $querys = DB::table('Business')->where([['Business.title','like','%'.$query.'%'],['Business.status','=',1]])
                        ->orWhere([['Business.description','like','%'.$query.'%'],['Business.status','=',1]]);

   $querys->join('socialtable','socialtable.userid','=','Business.userid'); 
   // Just join the social table
   $querys->where('socialtable.title',  'like','%'.$query.'%'); 
   $result = $querys->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Getting error!Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'brand' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `businesses` inner join `socialtable` on `socialtable`.`user_id` = `businesses`.`user_id` where (`title` like %adsasda% and `status` = 1) or (`description` like %adsasda% and `status` = 1) and `socialtable`.`title` like %adsasda%)

Comment: Did you got the solution? And sorry justnow i saw your comment

Comment: I think you modify your code after my answer, Did you please post your modified code

Comment: I have only modified the codes as suggested by you and am getting error as Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'brand' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: What about that error brand?? did you have any field named "brand" in your table

Comment: Instead of this $query = DB::table('Business') try this $querys = DB::table('Business')

Comment: `$querys = DB::table('businesses')->where([['title','like','%'.$query.'%'],['status','=',1]])
                        ->orWhere([['description','like','%'.$query.'%'],['status','=',1]]);

            $querys->join('franchisors','franchisors.user_id','=','businesses.user_id'); 
            // Just join the social table
            $querys->where('franchisors.title',  'like','%'.$query.'%'); 
            $search = $querys->paginate(10);

     return view('front.search',[
      'results' => $search,
      'query' => $query
     ]);`

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `businesses` inner join `franchisors` on `franchisors`.`user_id` = `businesses`.`user_id` where (`title` like %asd% and `status` = 1) or (`description` like %asd% and `status` = 1) and `franchisors`.`title` like %asd%)

Comment: Bro I updated my answer, So you just copy and paste it, Surely it works, and Do upvote and accept my answer

Comment: No... Still getting the same error Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from businesses inner join franchisors on franchisors.user_id = businesses.user_id where (title like %asd% and status = 1) or (description like %asd% and status = 1) and franchisors.title like %asd%) –

Comment: did you have title field in database ??? If you have, then which table you have title field

Comment: Yes. I do have `title` field in all types of posts table(business, franchisors, sociallife & so on )

Comment: Did you see my updated answer??? In every title I added table name infront (EX: business.title , franchisors.title). Add table name infront of every field

Comment: can u please re-post your answer with proper codes please?

Comment: I posted as a new answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model called Book, like this:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the author that wrote the book.
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve all of your books with authors like this:

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author'])->get();
```

Check out [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) from Laravel documentation.

Comment: Hey @Milos, This is not what I am asking for.Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**Just add table name before every field**

```
   $querys = DB::table('Business')->where([['Business.title','like','%'.$query.'%'],['Business.status','=',1]])
                        ->orWhere([['Business.description','like','%'.$query.'%'],['Business.status','=',1]]);

   $querys->join('socialtable','socialtable.userid','=','Business.userid'); 
   // Just join the social table
   $querys->where('socialtable.title',  'like','%'.$query.'%'); 
   $result = $querys->paginate(10);
```